# Pass an argument to function, assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to debounce some piece of my code and for this purpose I use the following function:

```
private debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

And then, in order to use it, I do this:

```
var showDataOnMove = this.debounce(function (evt) {
     console.log('moving');
 }, 500, false);
```

Which works just as intended, when I call it inside this piece of code:

```
this._map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
    showDataOnMove();
});
```

However, I realized, that I have like no idea how could I pass any argument to my debounced function, when it's attached to a variable (e.g. I want to pass this evt to showDataOnMove()), I tried different approaches, like this one:

```
var showDataOnMove = (evt) => this.debounce(function (evt) {
    console.log('moving');
    console.log(evt);
}, 500, false);
```

But it didn't work as well. How could I pass an argument to this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably creating a closure. You already do this, however you then redeclare the captured variable and thus break it. What this should look like is:

```
// Function in debounce has no argument
var showDataOnMove = evt => {
    this.debounce(() => {
        console.log('moving');
        console.log(evt);
    }, 500, false)(); // Call the function returned by debounce
};
```

---

Your initial version of assigning `showDataOnMove` should work just fine, here is a better typed example where `debouce` returns a function of the same type as the one passed in as argument:

```
class DebounceExample
{
    private debounce<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(func: T, wait: number, immediate: boolean): T
    {
        // Depending on environment (e.g. Node or browser) this should be typed differently
        var timeout: any;

        return function (this: any, ...args)
        {
            var context = this;
            var later = function ()
            {
                timeout = undefined;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

            if (callNow)
                func.apply(context, args);
        } as T;
    };

    constructor()
    {
        // Example usage
        var showDataOnMove = this.debounce(function (evt: number) {
            console.log(evt);
        }, 500, false);

        setTimeout(() => showDataOnMove(1));
        setTimeout(() => showDataOnMove(2));
        setTimeout(() => showDataOnMove(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reasons. When I call my `showDataOnMove(someThing) made this way, it doesn't work at all. Though I was also thinking about closures as a soltuion

Comment: Right, because your debounce returns a function. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, it works like a charm, thanks! Such a silly mistake from me, wasn't really paying attention that debounce returns a function.

Comment: @Aldres: Also, that should not really be necessary. With the way debounce it written, assigning directly to `showDataOnMove` should already work with arguments, so why did you try to do this?

Comment: Well, it actually might be some issue with the typescript. When I initially tried to pass an argument, TS gave me a compilation error.

Comment: @Aldres: That is to be expected, because you are trying to do something generic which loses all type information (working with `argument` and such).

Comment: @Aldres: (Added an example of how to type the `debounce` function a bit better)

Comment: Seems to be more suitable for typescript! Will use it indeed, thank you!